# Docker build with Alpine Linux causes segmentation fault

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I've been using `alpine/edge/community` and I guess something changed under the hood recently because I'm not able to build an image from my docker file anymore and I get a seg fault instead.

Output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  54.78kB

Step 1/6 : FROM ruby:2.5-alpine
2.5-alpine: Pulling from library/ruby

...

Status: Downloaded newer image for ruby:2.5-alpine
 ---> b14dcd6b80e9
Step 2/6 : RUN apk add --update build-base gcc && gem install bundler && mkdir -p /mnt/fileview
 ---> Running in f68bd52262b7
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/17) Installing binutils (2.35.1-r1)
(2/17) Installing libmagic (5.39-r0)
(3/17) Installing file (5.39-r0)
(4/17) Installing libgomp (10.2.1_pre1-r3)
(5/17) Installing libatomic (10.2.1_pre1-r3)
(6/17) Installing libgphobos (10.2.1_pre1-r3)
(7/17) Installing isl22 (0.22-r0)
[91mSegmentation fault (core dumped)
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update build-base gcc && gem install bundler && mkdir -p /mnt/fileview' returned a non-zero code: 139
```

Docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine
RUN apk add --update build-base gcc && gem install bundler && mkdir -p /mnt/fileview
WORKDIR /mnt/fileview
COPY * ./
RUN bundle install --deployment
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "ruby", "viewer_app.rb"]
```

It looks like `isl22` was added as a dependency to alpine v3.13 aka the new latest version and that might be causing issues. However I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you fixed the problem, I am facing the same issue.@en13

Answer (score 0):

I cannot build the given `Dockerfile` due to an error when invoking the bundle_install command:

```
DESKTOP-SI79RLD:~/test$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine
RUN apk add --update build-base gcc && gem install bundler && mkdir -p /mnt/fileview
WORKDIR /mnt/fileview
COPY * ./
RUN bundle install --deployment
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "ruby", "viewer_app.rb"]

DESKTOP-SI79RLD:~/test$ docker build .
[+] Building 1.2s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 263B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:2.5-alpine                                                 0.7s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 257B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:2.5-alpine@sha256:009796beb93df8dc2d51aa07efd2b6e7e5b26504688e7ce0db25cec52  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] RUN apk add --update build-base gcc && gem install bundler && mkdir -p /mnt/fileview              0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] WORKDIR /mnt/fileview                                                                             0.0s
 => [4/5] COPY * ./                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN bundle install --deployment                                                                    0.4s
------
 > [5/5] RUN bundle install --deployment:
#9 0.353 [DEPRECATED] The `--deployment` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set --local deployment 'true'`, and stop using this flag
#9 0.383 Could not locate Gemfile
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bundle install --deployment]: exit code: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had base alpine version as v3.12, and changed the source list to come from edge, causing segmentation fault.

Using v3.12 sources instead fixed the issue. You can also try gradual upgrades, it seems the issue was that the leap forward was too big.